# Select Maximum record

Tags: oracle

Here is my Table  `EMP_EARN_DETAILS`.

`Emp_Ern_No` is the primary key.

I need to get the amount for each `emp_no` for each  `earn_no` where the `emp_earn_no` is the *maximum*.

[image]

The output should be as follows.

```
0004321    ERN001           2345          11
0004321    ERN002            345          10
0004321    ERN003            345           9
000507     ER-01             563           4 
000732     ERN001            2345          12
000732     ERN002               9          13
000732     ERN003             678           8
```

Please help me with the query

Comment: Why have a screen shot?

Comment: What select statement have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate by the fields you need and, at the same time, order by the EMP_EARN_NO value; this can be a solution, by analytic functions:

```
    WITH TEST(emp_no, earn_no, amount, emp_earn_no) AS
   (
    SELECT '0004321' , 'ERN001'   ,2345 ,11   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '0004321' , 'ERN002'   ,345  , 10  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '0004321' , 'ERN003'   ,345  ,9    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '000507'  , 'ER-01'    ,56   ,1    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '000507'  , 'ER-01'    ,563  , 2   FROM DUAL UNION ALL    
    SELECT '000507'  , 'ER-01'    ,563  ,3    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '000507'  , 'ER-01'    ,563  ,4    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '00732'   , 'ERN001'   ,123  ,7    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '00732'   , 'ERN001'   ,2345 ,12   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '00732'   , 'ERN002'   ,9    ,13   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '00732'   , 'ERN003'   ,67   ,5    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '00732'   , 'ERN003'   ,456  ,6    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT '00732'   , 'ERN003'   ,678  ,8    FROM DUAL
    )
SELECT emp_no, earn_no, amount, emp_earn_no
FROM (
        SELECT emp_no,
        earn_no,
        amount,
        emp_earn_no, ROW_NUMBER()  OVER ( PARTITION BY EMP_NO, EARN_NO ORDER BY emp_earn_no DESC) AS ROW_NUM
        FROM TEST
     )
WHERE ROW_NUM = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot,

```
SELECT EMP_NO, SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM EMP_EARN_DETAILS
GROUP BY EMP_NO
HAVING EMP_EARN_NO = MAX(EMP_EARN_NO)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select emp_no, earn_no,
       sum(amount) keep (dense_rank last order by emp_earn_no) as sum_amount
from emp_earn_details
group by emp_no, earn_no
```

Answer (score 0):

First by following query , your conditions achieved :

```
select t.emp_no a ,t.earn_no b ,max(t.amount) c
    from EMP_EARN_DETAILS t 
    group by t.emp_no,t.earn_no 
    order by t.emp_no
```

Only things that you must specify , in a same record with different `EMP_EARN_NO`. You have to specify in same record which must be in result.
So if you want maximum `EMP_EARN_NO` be in result you can use following query as final query (exactly your target in question):

```
select t.emp_no a ,t.earn_no b ,max(t.amount) c, max(t.emp_earn_no) emp_earn_no
    from EMP_EARN_DETAILS t 
    group by t.emp_no,t.earn_no 
    order by t.emp_no
```

If you want minimum or others `EMP_EARN_NO` be in result you can above query replace max function by your conditions.